# Why do my Firestore rules prevent me from getting my documents?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am setting my firebase rules, and I have one query that keeps throwing back at me `Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions`.

I've looked at my rules and tried to figure out what I might be doing wrong, but can't find what it is.

This is my query:

```
  const data = await db
    .collection("templates")
    .where("user_ID", "==", userID)
    .get()
```

And these are my relevant rules:

```
match /templates/{template}{
  allow read, write, delete: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.user_ID;
}
```

I only have this one rule for the `templates` collection, so there's no overwriting issues happening.

Each document in this collection has a field `user_ID` which is the uid of the user who posted it.

I currently have just one document there for testing.

What am I doing wrong to get that error?

If I change it to just be `if true` then I stop getting this error - so I know that this rule is the one causing the issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation):

> The `resource` variable refers to the requested document, and
>   `resource.data` is a map of all of the fields and values stored in the
>   document.
>
> When **writing** data, you may want to compare incoming data to existing
>   data. In this case, if your ruleset allows the pending write, the
>   `request.resource` variable contains the future state of the document.

So your rule is not correct when you want to read, it should be:

```
match /templates/{template}{
  allow read: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.user_ID;
  allow write: ....
}
```

---

FYI, it's really worth watching the [official video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eW5MdE3ZcAw&feature=youtu.be).